# Перевод строк char в wchar_t

Tags: c, c++, linux

Есть ли в Linux стандартная библиотечная функция, переводящая строки  `char` в строки `wchar_t`?

Comment: Не уверен, но, возможно, Вам нужна функция `mbstowcs` из `cstdlib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Вариантов, как всегда, несколько.*

- Самый разумный - использование `std::use_facet` из стандартной библиотеки, метод в таком случае может выглядеть следующим образом *(этот вариант - это мое расширение `boost::lexical_cast`)*:

---

```
namespace boost {

template <>
inline std::wstring lexical_cast<std::wstring, std::string>(const std::string& arg) {

   std::wstring result;
   std::locale locale;

   // Use specific (character-driven) facet for current result.
   for (std::size_t i= 0; i < arg.size(); ++i) {
      result += std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t> >(locale).widen(arg[i]);
   }

   return result;
}

template <> 
inline std::string lexical_cast<std::string, std::wstring>(const std::wstring& arg) {

   std::string result;
   std::locale locale;

   // Use specific (character-driven) facet for current result.
   for (std::size_t i= 0; i < arg.size(); ++i) {
      result += std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t> >(locale).narrow(arg[i]);
   }

   return result;
}
```

---

- Дальше - вариации на тему `::mbstowcs` *(код с просторов инета)*

---

```
struct String
{
    wchar_t* string;
    size_t length;
};

void SetStrIntoWcharObj(String *obj, const char *str)
{
    obj->length = ::mbstowcs(0, src, 0);
    obj->string = ::realloc(obj->string, (obj->length + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));

    std::size_t length = ::mbstowcs(obj->string, str, obj->length + 1);

    // Случай, когда конвертация не удалась (::mbstowcs вернет -1)
    if (length == std::(size_t) - 1) FAIL;

    // Как обрабатывать FAIL - решать уже вам.
}
```

---

- Использовать `libiconv`. Смотрите [**примеры.**](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/iconv-Examples.html)

**Решать, разумеется, вам, но (на мой взгляд) преимущества использования `std::use_facet` и `widen` очевидны.**

Comment: По ходу дела несколько вопросов к знатокам темы. 

Символы в wchar_t (2 байта) это UTF-16 или UCS-2 ? 

Если UTF-16, то как в программах решается вопрос UTF-16LE или UTF-16ВE ? 

Есть ли устоявшиеся правила использования BOM (Byte order mark) в программах с wchar_t ?

Никогда руки не доходили толком исследовать и реализовать это (UTF-16) в своих программах перекодировки.

Comment: В Линуксе wchar_t  занимает 4 байта. Хранятся там данные, как я понимаю, в UTF-8

Comment: Или UCS-4 (Собственно юникод)? Или UTF-32 и UCS-4 это одно и то же ?

Comment: Я так понимаю, UCS-4 - это таблица кодировки символов, а разные UTF - ее представления в виде последовательности байтов.

экспериментально определил, что в лине используется UTF-32ΒΕ.

Comment: На Solaris, например, из-за endianness будет `UTF-32BE`.

Comment: Если работает на Spark, а на PC, думаю, та же ситуация будет

Comment: И все таки, в 2-х байтном wchar_t UTF-16 или UCS-2 ? 

Посмотрел в Ubuntu (32-разрядная) - 4 байта. Видимо надо считать, что тут будет UCS-4 (в машинном (x86) представлении будет UTF-32LE).

Comment: UTF-32 == UCS-4, UTF-16 != UCS-2, а является ее надмножеством.

Windows использует UTF-16.

При этом, UCS-2 encoding is defined to be big-endian only.

Comment: @skegg: И тут вижу [такой же миф](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/425646). В wchar_t хранится (во всяком случае, при следовании POSIX) кодовая позиция символа Unicode (максимальное значение: 0x10FFFD). Короче, UTF-32. Похоже, Вы не понимаете, решением каких задач занимается UTF-8, и какова его роль в Linux.

Поиграйтесь [вот с этим](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbstowcs.3.html) (как с собственно функцией mbstowcs, так и  с форматом вывода `%lc`. Надеюсь, квалификации сделать тестовую программу на Си хватит? Не забудьте только в начале вызвать setlocale, не то ничего не будет работать.

Comment: @avp: Внутри программ имеет место нативный порядок байт. Только они оперируют сразу 16- и 32-битными словами. В случае UTF-32 — просто кодовая позиция, в случае UTF-16 — код UTF-16 (совпадающий с кодовой позицией для символов Основной Плоскости). Считайте, что в «байте UTF-16» 16 бит. Всё сказанное — за исключением случая, когда надо прочесть данные, записанные в противном данной платформе порядке байт.