# Как unicode code point переводится в отображаемый символ?

Tags: linux, windows, utf-8, unicode

К примеру, UTF-8 символ `Я` закодирован в `1101 0000 1010 1111`, а после декодирования получается code point `1 0000 10 1111`. Так вот, кто отвечает за превращение этого code point в символ и отрисовку на экране? То есть, в windows и linux есть таблицы Unicode по которым ищется этот code point и потом отрисовывается glyph ему соответствующий? В Linux все в UTF-8, а в windows в api функции нужно передавать UTF-16 c сурогатными парами?

Comment: Code point никуда дальше не переводится.  `1 0000 10 1111` - это и есть код символа `я`, единственный и неповторимый )  Некоторые шрифты содержат глиф для этого символа, некоторые нет.

Answer (score 3):

ответ вынесен из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425646/#comment434310_425646):

---

*Code point* никуда дальше не переводится. `1 0000 10 1111` - это и есть код символа `я`, единственный и неповторимый.

Некоторые шрифты содержат *глиф* для этого символа, некоторые — нет.

Answer (score 2):

Шрифтовая машина отвечает за преобразование code point в изображение.
Поскольку шрифты индексированы (в современных системах) code pointами в Unicode, то ожидается, что разбирающее строку ПО умеет разбираться с конкретной используемой кодировкой. И, кстати, не имеет принципиального значения, применяется Unicode-кодировка или что-то иное. ПО отображения текста должно уметь преобразовать строку байт в последовательность Unicode code points. Не принципиально, в чём строку: UTF-8, UTF-16 или Code Page 1251.

«В Linux все в UTF-8» — миф. Несомненно, ядро поддерживает UTF-8 во многих ситуациях, но внутри ядерного ПО текстовой консоли символы обрабатываются в виде 16-разрядных опять-таки Unicode code points, т.е. в UCS-2, а хранятся обычно (см. `/dev/vcsa`*n*) — и вовсе в 8- или 9-битных кодовых страницах. Имена файлов? Не знаю, в каком месте ядра и с каких пор фиксируется использование для них UTF-8; ещё в 2.x можно было при монтировании FAT и SMB указать преобразование в разные кодовые страницы. Как в современном Linux — дополните знатоки, если знаете. А прикладное ПО в tty может работать в любой кодировке, для которой не поленились создать локаль.

Использование UTF-16LE в ядре Windows ускоряет задачу при выводе символов Основной Плоскости (BMP; code point < 0x10000), поскольку 16-разрядное слово UTF-16 в этом случае — оно же code point. Когда Windows натыкается на суррогатную пару — да, она преобразуется в 32-разрядный код и по нему проводится поиск в шрифте.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, в именах файлов (по крайней мере в FS типа ext4) могут присутствовать *любые* байты (конечно, кроме `/` и `0x00`) и никаких преобразований кодировок на пути от open (fopen) к оглавлению на диске никто не делает. А вот имена в подмонтированных "чужих" файловых системах у меня конвертируются в utf-8 (подозреваю, что это зависит от locale, может кто проверит? а то мне экспериментировать лень).

Comment: @avp: Сомневаюсь, что от локали, т.к. локаль не перекодирует имена файлов на пути к системным вызовам (иначе говоря, в open() как строка байт входит, так то же самое приходит в ядро). А на ядро локаль не действует принципиально, т.к. реализуется средствами userspace. У некоторых файловых систем (включая те, что я назвал) при *монтировании* есть опции `-o iocharset=` и `-o codepage=`.

Comment: У меня сейчас (вывод mount) `ushare on /media/sf_ushare type vboxsf (gid=1001,rw)` делится между VirtualBox в винде и Linux. / Считаете, что в VboxAdditions (видимо в реализацию open для конкретной FS в vfs) зашито utf-8? / А в  принципе данные locale (как environment `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`) из userspace внутри kernel доступны (как ими там можно дольше воспользоваться -- это уже другой вопрос).

Comment: @avp: Если я понял о чём речь, host-система монтирует ФС виртуального Windows, выступающего файл-сервером. Раз в Windows NT+ имена файлов закодированы в UTF-16, вполне логично преобразовывать их в UTF-8 а не во что-нибудь 8-битное ограничительное, во избежание недоступных файлов и иных неприятностей.

Да, ядро может подсмотреть локаль. Только его поведение должно основываться не на капризе системного программиста, а на семантике. Так повелось, что open() в UNIX-системах берёт строку байт, а не символов. Сменить это для всех приложений — нереально, а постепенно — глюки и дыры в безопасности.

Comment: Поток байт это как раз нормально. А вот то, что я не могу положить в винду файл с имененм не в utf-8 (например, `\377.txt` (`я.txt` в cp-1251)), который само-собой не может быть перекодирован в виндозный UTF-16 -- вот это ненормально. Впрочем, надеюсь, скоро винду (после проколов в шпионящей 10-ке) мы будем только вспоминать.

Comment: @avp: Зависит от выбора определения операции «положить в винду». Создать в 8-битном (в смысле использования так называемого [ACP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#ANSI_code_page)) приложении? Можете. Записать на устройство с файловой системой FAT16 и потом прочесть в винде? Тоже нет проблем. А вот создать через  [NT API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API) или [W-функцию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Юникод_в_операционных_системах_семейства_Microsoft_Windows) — не можете. Но и то не потому, что API откажет. А оттого, что в 16-битной кодировке нет такой вещи как \377.

Comment: Естественно, \377 это вне utf-8 (соответственно вне юникода и следовательно ни в utf-16 ни в каком другом формате юникода не представляется). / Кстати, я все же немного поэкспериментировал с setlocale() и environmen -- не зависит. Т.е. для обмена с виндой  поток байт имени файла в  лине должен быть строго из utf-8.